# How to format numeric string?

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

My text with not format is: `100000.00`

I format it to: `("0:0,0 POINT")` and I want it to: `100,000` POINT

But I have no luck. So, how can it format it to `100,000` POINT?

```
txtpoint.Text = string.Format("{0:0,0} POINT",(table_ca.Compute("SUM(POINT)", "")).ToString());
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your actual code. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Thanks you. I improved my question !

Comment: What does **table_ca.Compute("SUM(POINT)", "")** return?

Comment: It's return a cmd select from datatable 
But i'm done by @Ruskin's helping. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
string.Format("{0:n0} POINT", 100000)
```

Comment: This might be right, but it's generally best to wait until the question is actually clear enough to answer correctly.

Comment: I'm try with your code but it's not working, please view my code below. Thank for your help, my friend !!!